# How can I add to an existing value in sql table

Tags: sql, json, database, sql-update

How can i add a value to an existing value in SQL example a value 4 in a column how can i add 2 to it to make it 6 not to update to 2 but to add the previous value and the new value to together here is my class php file

```
<?php
class data
{
    
    public $d_count;
    public $id;
    
    private $conn;
    private $table_name;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
        $this->table_name= "tbl_data";
    }
    
    public function updateCount()
    {
       
        //  $query = "UPDATE tbl_data SET d_count = ?, date_updated = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $query = "UPDATE tbl_data SET d_count '+1' = ?, date_updated = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $obj = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        
        $this->d_count  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->d_count));
        $this->date_updated  = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->date_updated));
        $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

        $obj->bind_param("sss", $this->d_count, $this->date_updated, $this->id);

        if ($obj->execute()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
   

}
```

The line I commented out is what i used to test the code and it works fine but now i need to add the old value + new value together here is the code am using to update the table

```
<?php

$data = new data($connection);
 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
    
    $newDCount = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if(!empty($newDCount->d_count))
    $data->id= $newDCount->id;
    $data->d_count = $newDCount->d_count;
    $data->date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

    if($apiata->updateCount()){
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode(array(
            "status" => 200,
            "message" => "Success"
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => 500,
        "message" => "Failed"
        ));
    }
 
}
```

Comment: *"`htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(...))`"* - Why are you using these? They won't help against sql injection. It might even work against you. Just stick to prepared statements and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks can i get a sample of the prepared statement am fairly new to PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the `d_count` to add to the existing `d_count` value, the query should look like:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE catalog SET d_count = d_count + ?, date_updated = ? WHERE id = ?';
```

The other handling should be ok as-is.